# k_log function in Keras for R: Is it the logarithm for the base e (natural logartihm) or for the base 10?

Tags: r, keras

I wonder whether the (Keras for R backend-) function `k_log(x)` represents the natural logartihm or the logarithm to another base like e.g `10`?

The [official documentation](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/k_log.html) only states

> Element-wise log.

Comment: Arguably, doing the simple experiment yourself would be a much more efficient way for finding out instead of opening a question here, wouldn't it?

Comment: Of course you're right. However, doing this simple experiment requires a stable connection of R to tensorflow, which is often not as easy to obtain as one might think at first glance. There are tons of questions that refer to this problem. So for one who has successfully built this connection, it's a matter of seconds to answer the question. For one who first has to build this connection, it's often a matter of several hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the natural logarithm.

```
k_log(10)
# tf.Tensor(2.3025851, shape=(), dtype=float32)

log(10)
# [1] 2.302585
```